# Discussion pagination in elgg 1.8 is not working properly

Tags: elgg

We have a website created using elgg, and we have discussion part of elgg where pagination is not working properly.

When listing all discussion list, pagination is working correctly, from latest to oldest

But pagination inside topic (one of the discussion) where replies are too many, and they separated by pagination (Previous, next), it is showing replies incorrectly:

In the first page we have: [image: The first page]

As you can see it is ordered from latest to oldest: 17 days ago and then comes 21 days ago.

But when you go next page: [image: Page 2]

It is ordered inside the page from latest to oldest, but the the pages should be swapped.

How can I fix it?

Thanks forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found finally going through all pagination libraries, and annotation views.

The problem is when listing replies for discussion on **replies.php** file which in **/views/default/discussion** there are two jquery functions on the bottom of the page that reverse the order.

```
function reverse(arr){
    var newArr = [];
    for(var iter = arr.length -1; iter >= 0; iter--){
        newArr.push(arr[iter])
    }

    return newArr;
}
```

I have change the iter to start from 0 and go to arr.lenthg.

But it is not all yet, in order to get the latest replies first, I have added to

```
$options = array(
'guid' => $vars['entity']->getGUID(),
'annotation_name' => 'group_topic_post',
```

);

this line:

```
'order_by'=> 'time_created desc'
```

And then I got my replies ordered correctly: from latest to oldest.

Answer (score 0):

It works properly. Discussions are ordered by last action on the thread. You may have older thread first due to it having most recent response of all threads.

To change it, look at `discussion_handle_list_page` function in `mod/groups/lib/discussion` and how it uses `order_by` parameter. You need to override this page and just remove `order_by` to use default ordering, which is creation time of the entity (in his case thread). You could do it by tapping to the "route" plugin hook, or overriding whole discussions page handler.

And that's why not just change it inline: http://learn.elgg.org/en/1.9/guides/dont-modify-core.html

Comment: I have changed the function discussion_handle_list_page() changed order_by to be desc and asc, I does not change at all even though I change from desc to asc. And I also noticed that limit parameter is set to be 20, but on the page it shows 25. Is it maybe controlled somewhere else? It is really weird though.

Comment: Can you please example, links, readings to how to do "route" plugin hook and overriding page handler?